# EF Code first error when seeding with composite key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I have an entity with a composite, primary key (Id and TreeVersion). I have another entity with values that reference this key.

First entity:

```
class ClassificationType
{
  [Key]
  [Column(Order = 1)
  public int Id {get;set;}

  [Key]
  [Column(Order = 2, Type="varchar")]
  [StringLength("100")]
  public string TreeVersion {get;set}
}
```

Second entity:

```
class ClassConfig
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int? ClassificationTypeId { get; set; }
  [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
  [StringLength(10)]
  public string TreeVersion { get; set; }
}
```

With this in place, everything works fine - I can seed my tables with data and everything is peachy.

However, when I try to add a navigation property (and thereby foreign key from second entity to first entity), seeding fails.

I add this line to second entity:

```
public virtual ClassificationType ClassificationType {get;set;}
```

This causes this migration step:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ClassConfig");
    AlterColumn("dbo.ClassConfig", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ClassConfig", "Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.ClassConfig", new[] { "Id", "TreeVersion" });
    AddForeignKey("dbo.ClassConfig", new[] { "Id", "TreeVersion" }, "dbo.ClassificationTypes", new[] { "Id", "TreeVersion" });
}
```

Notice how it actually fails in deducting the foreign key columns, so I manually change this to

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ClassConfig");
    AlterColumn("dbo.ClassConfig", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ClassConfig", "Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.ClassConfig", new[] { "ClassificationTypeId", "TreeVersion" });
    AddForeignKey("dbo.ClassConfig", new[] { "ClassificationTypeId", "TreeVersion" }, "dbo.ClassificationTypes", new[] { "Id", "TreeVersion" });
}
```

This creates the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClassConfig] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ClassConfig]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClassConfig] ALTER COLUMN [Id] [int] NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClassConfig] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ClassConfig] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
CREATE INDEX [IX_ClassificationTypeId_TreeVersion] ON [dbo].[ClassConfig]([ClassificationTypeId], [TreeVersion])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClassConfigEntries] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ClassConfig_dbo.ClassificationTypes_ClassificationTypeId_TreeVersion] FOREIGN KEY ([ClassificationTypeId], [TreeVersion]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ClassificationTypes] ([Id], [TreeVersion])
```

Now, when I seed my tables, the script fails. The message is this:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'ClassConfigEntries' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? The values I am trying to insert into the ClassConfig table are present in the ClassificationType table at point of insertion.

I have about 30 existing tables in out model, some of them with identity specified, and all of them work as they should when seeding and navigation properties are available when getting values from the database. It is only this corner of my model, that causes me head aches.

Comment: I would say, something in your model is missing indicating that Id is `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`

Comment: OK - where would I put that? And - wouldn't that be covered by EF conventions saying that an column with name "Id" is considered primary key?

Comment: It should be covered by conventions. But your report says other. The name `ClassCongigEntities` sounds weirds too. I expect `ClassConfigs`.

Comment: Hi @tschmit007, sorry - my bad. I c/p'ed text from the wrong place. The SQL-code is updated now. Something that also puzzles me is the error stating that IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. I am pretty sure that EF migrations sets this flag to ON when starting seeding (otherwise all my other seedings to other tables would fail)

Comment: Did you configure the relationship to ClassificationType somewhere? Either using fluent api or data annotations?

Comment: Adding [ForeignKey("ClassificationTypeId", "TreeVersion")] to ClassificationType navigation property might help. But I'm unsure if it's the cause of the problem

Comment: @Toni all code I have is what you see above. But I tried your suggestion, and that seems to have fixed the issue for me. The scaffolded migration step now only contains the AddForeignKey-code, as I would have expected. Thank you :-)